# Clicking a link displays address in URL but doesn't open the page

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, permalinks, theming

I am creating a theme on wordpress with Bootstrap CDN. I created a button as:

```
 <div class="col-md-4"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"
  class="btn btn-lg btn-block">Read Latest</a></div>
```

It displays link as button and when I click it, url bar displays the link that should be opened, but page doesn't open. 
I know this is a very noob question but I'm stuck, any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Update:
The Resulting html link to the php I used is: http://localhost/baatega/bad-day-eh/

Comment: What is the URL after click?

Comment: That is quite odd, please check if you haven't any js doing something nasty. Plus, try with another browser. Do some tests.

Comment: Thanks for comment, I am developing it on Firefox in linux with LAMP installed, I tried it on chromium but nopes, same problem. I have disabled cache so I think browser is not a problem here. There is no javascript in my theme so far so I don't think it's js problem either. Update: refreshing the page brings the page I want but clicking the link still don't bring up the page directly.

Comment: after click, the url is the link to latest post that I want to open, i mean url displays the link but page doesn't opening. Hope you're getting me, sorry for bad english.

Comment: The above is the php code. Can you copy the resulting HTML code and include it in your question, thanks.

Comment: just updated question, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I don't quite understand the issue - the link is not correct? or what? Could you paste here please print screen or reproduce the issue in jsFiddle? It's more or less question for the WordPress development forum here, however if it's the case of link:

1. Check if `get_permalink();` is used within the Loop. (if not, you have to pass the ID as an argument to it)
2. try to echo the escaped url: `esc_url( get_permalink() );`

Have a look here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/

Comment: Link is correct, when I inspect element of the link, it shows the path that should open, I am not using this inside a loop. escaped url shows the same result. THE PROBLEM: when I click the button, the link (html) get displayed in URL bar but page won't open. Refreshing it, opens the page. I don't know who to post jsfiddle of the php code.

Comment: Thanks kybernaut, I figured it out from the link you've posted. I am using it wrong all along. Thanks !

Comment: you should share the answer